# Error when creating criteria from model with defaultScope attributes come from joined model

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I have add parameter from joined attribute (`event.deleted_at`, `event.status`) in `defaultScope` method Model:

```
public function defaultScope()
{
    return array(
            'condition'=>'
                lp_deleted_at is NULL 
                AND event.e_deleted_at IS NULL
                AND event.status = TRUE
        '
    );
}
```

Error in last line (`addSearchCondition`)when creating criteria:

```
 $criteria=new CDbCriteria;



     $criteria->with = array( 
                                     'lokasi_pengamatan'=>array('select'=>'lokasi_pengamatan.nama','together'=>true),
                                     'event'=>array('select'=>'event.id_event','together'=>true)

   $criteria->addSearchCondition('lokasi_pengamatan.nama', '%'.$this->lokasi_pengamatan.'%', false, 'AND', 'ILIKE');
```

Error Message

```
Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "event"
```

Comment: Did you make relations between both the tables? You've to define relations in both the models.

Comment: Yes, the default relations generated by gii are exists

Answer (score 0):

I usually write the SQL using CDbCriteria a bit different:

```
private function searchByUser(){
    $criteria         = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = 'QuestionForm.*';
    $criteria->addCondition('QuestionForm.user_id = $this->user_id');
    return $this->with(array('QuestionForm'))->findAll($criteria);
}
```